# Trying to Add Items to QTableWidget from QThread Works but Throws Error

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have to update my QTableWidget, but it has a ton of data so I threaded updating it:

```
self.vthread = visualThread(self.data_view, data)
self.vthread.start()
```

`self.data_view` is a QTableWidget, and `data` is a class object which has some list attributes I need to iterate through and put in the table. This is the thread:

```
class visualThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, view, data):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.view = view
        self.data= data

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        for y in range(len(self.data.axis[0])):
            for x in range(len(self.data.axis[0])):
                self.view.setItem(x, y, QTableWidgetItem(str(maintain_order_sort(self.data.data_array[x][y][::-1]))))
```

`maintain_order_sort` just reorganizes the string.
This is my output:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

I've tried adding signals (I have another thread that works with signals, this is the only error one), and I've pinpointed the error down to `setItem()`. TIA

Comment: **Basic rule of Qt and PyQt, the GUI is never modified from another thread** other than the main thread, the main thread is called the GUI thread!!!!

Comment: When I try doing that, my GUI becomes unresponsive. I essentially had the same code as above, except instead of `setItem`, I emitted the data to a function which updated the table.

Comment: call to `QApplication.processEvents()`

Comment: Go figure. The easiest solution is the simplest. THanks.

Comment: did find the solution ? because i have the same problem